# Is there a size limit on substrate messages?

Tags: networking, security

So, substrate uses a bunch of network messages like block announce, grandpa message, block request-response, transaction. Substrate has notification substream open sending and receiving these messages and may be some other data as well.
I expect that there might be some limit on size of the data substrate receives, because otherwise people can send huge amount of data to do DoS. So, is there a size limit on these network messages and how much?
For more context, look at https://github.com/ChainSafe/gossamer/issues/2399

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different subprotocols are using different limits:

- request/response protocols: 16MB ([blocks](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ee3eb8f2448cc1bb978c5d1564febd351c128bb0/client/network/sync/src/block_request_handler.rs#L71), [state](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ee3eb8f2448cc1bb978c5d1564febd351c128bb0/client/network/sync/src/state_request_handler.rs#L58), [light](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ee3eb8f2448cc1bb978c5d1564febd351c128bb0/client/network/light/src/light_client_requests.rs#L39), [warp](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ee3eb8f2448cc1bb978c5d1564febd351c128bb0/client/network/sync/src/warp_request_handler.rs#L46))
- notifications: [grandpa](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ee3eb8f2448cc1bb978c5d1564febd351c128bb0/client/finality-grandpa/src/lib.rs#L733) 1MB, [transactions](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ee3eb8f2448cc1bb978c5d1564febd351c128bb0/client/network/src/transactions.rs#L68) 16MB, [block announcements](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ee3eb8f2448cc1bb978c5d1564febd351c128bb0/client/network/src/protocol.rs#L93) 1MB